# Black-Box for example

Tags: black-box-testing, black-box

I read about black-box testing [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).
I would love to try to learn Black-Box testing techniques but the problem is that I can not find any site that provides Black-Box examples.
Is there a site that does this? Perhaps websites like  (only with Black-Boxes)?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably learned, BlackBox testing is a technique that you can apply to anything, not just software.

From your question, it looks like you are looking for real-life examples where you can see this technique in action. I recommend continuing your research and googling more examples, such as [here](http://www.onestoptesting.com/blackbox-testing/example.asp), or [here](http://www.testingbrain.com/blackbox/black-box-testing.html).

The best way to get a grasp of this technique is to use it on software you have wrote yourself! (just pretend to be testing from an outsider's perspective)

Answer (score 1):

Black box testing is a method of testing where you don't know how the features were implemented.  You can black box test *any* piece of software.  This site for instance or Microsoft Word.

The "Black Box" refers to the piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Black-box test for example

1. User name input field,displays “username”by default
2. Password input field, displays “password”by default
3. Login button  - when pressed validate :
      Both fields filled in 
      Username exits in system
      Password at least 6 characters